# He laughs best who laughs last

Tags: meaning

He laughs best who laughs last.

Can anyone tell me what the above sentence means?

From the structure of the sentence, the clause 'who laughs last' is the object of the verb 'laugh' and 'best' is the adverb modifying the verb 'laugh'. So my guess is: The person (He) laughs at anyone who is the final guy who laughs (at the joke). But I can't figure out how the adverb 'best' fits in, in terms of meaning.

Comment: The word "who" in this example, is not employed as an interrogative but as a relative pronoun. So another way of putting it is "He that laughs last, laughs best". Or as I have always understood it "He who laughs last, laughs longest".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"The person (He) laughs at anyone who is the final guy who laughs (at the joke)"*

This is not the meaning or how it is used.

It is all about fate and revenge.

Imagine that you have a very bad landlord and he evicts you and your family from the house. Also, he laughs as he does this. However, when he walks into the house, the house collapses and injures him badly - you laugh. But your laughter is better than his earlier laughter.
You have laughed last and you have laughed best.

Comment: This does not really answer the question, which was about the syntax.

Comment: Before downvoting, please read the question and ensure that you understand it.. The question was not about syntax at all. It was "Can anyone tell me what the above sentence means?"

Comment: I didn't downvote. You're right that the first question was about the meaning, you did discuss that, so I retract my comment. However, given the rest of the question, the OP was struggling to understand the syntax, and I think it would have been helpful to explain that.

Answer (score 3):

Like many proverbs and old sayings, this has an unusual syntax.

A more normal order would be

> He who laughs last laughs best

or, more clearly

> The one who laughs last [is the one who] laughs best.

I know it in the form "He who laughs last laughs longest". The same idea is present in the idiom "getting the last laugh".